# Airflow - Accessing the REST API from airflow running in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I currently have airflow running in a Kubernetes cluster in Azure using the helm chart for Apache airflow. I am able to use the API from the VM where I port forward the web server, using the endpoint: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/test_trigger/dagRuns

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how I can interact with the API from other locations, or just expose the API endpoint in general to be able to be called from other locations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a short chapter in Airflow Helm Chart's Production Guide:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#accessing-the-airflow-ui

It's about setting up Ingress or LoadBalancer essentially.

Accessing the API server is the same as accessing the webserver - they use the same port/run on webserver, so the pointes there should guide you what to do.